# NSTableView with blurry NSTextField on non-Retina screens

Tags: nstableview, retina-display

On macOS 10.14.5, I have a view-based NSTableView and one column contains an NSTextField. When highlighted and shown on a Retina screen, it looks good, but on a non-Retina screen it looks terrible. How can I fix this?

Non-Retina Screen:

[image: non-Retina]

Retina Screen:

[image: retina]

The first column's NSTextField has the same properties as the second column's NSTextField, so I really don't know why they look different.

A curiosity is that if I reorder the two columns during runtime, both look good, but if I set them up that way at build time, the Path column is still messed up.

Comment: Do you have any non-integer coordinates on your NSTextView? I have found that causes issues with text clarity.

Comment: The view is positioned on an integer coordinate and the widths of the columns are integers too.